# Use any apply method to find difference between max and min score for each students

Tags: r, lapply

here is the list of scores

```
Scores<-list(T = c(10,8,7,9), M = c(9,10,8,7), L = c(6,8,10), B = c(10,9,10,7,8))
```

I tried using lapply() function unsuccessfully, I am new to R and just trying to solve some exercise problem. What's the best way to approach this problem

Answer (score 6):

If you are just starting out, this is more difficult because you will likely want to pass what is known as an anonymous function to `lapply()` as opposed to something readily available like `mean`. Here is how to do that:

```
Scores <- list(T = c(10,8,7,9), M = c(9,10,8,7), L = c(6,8,10), B = c(10,9,10,7,8))

lapply(Scores, function(x) diff(range(x)))

# $T
# [1] 3
#
# $M
# [1] 3
#
# $L
# [1] 4
#
# $B
# [1] 3
```

Comment: A similar method that might be easier to read later is ```lapply(Scores, function(x) max(x) - min(x))```.  On this very small dataset, using the ```max(x) - min(x)``` way is more performant.